# react native java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request

Tags: java, react-native, gradle

I was just getting started with react native and I encountered some problem while building the app.

Here's the error:
(Complete log)

```
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew installDebug)...
AAPT err(Facade for 33021040): /home/srijan/Android/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2: 1: /home/srijan/Android/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Slave 33021040 failed to start
java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at /home/srijan/Android/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2) are not corrupted.
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:193)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
AAPT err(Facade for 26937763): /home/srijan/Android/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2: 1: /home/srijan/Android/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
Slave 26937763 failed to start
java.lang.RuntimeException: AAPT slave failed to start. Please make sure the current build tools (located at /home/srijan/Android/build-tools/27.0.3/aapt2) are not corrupted.
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReadyOrFail(AaptProcess.java:193)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptQueueThreadContext.creation(AaptQueueThreadContext.java:56)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:250)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_2"     java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%1$s'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2525)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.AaptGradleFactory$FilteringLogger.shouldDowngrade(AaptGradleFactory.java:156)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.AaptGradleFactory$FilteringLogger.error(AaptGradleFactory.java:122)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "queued-resource-processor_1"  

java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%1$s'
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2525)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
    at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.AaptGradleFactory$FilteringLogger.shouldDowngrade(AaptGradleFactory.java:156)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.aapt.AaptGradleFactory$FilteringLogger.error(AaptGradleFactory.java:122)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:253)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
```

So this is the error
Kindly help me troubleshoot this thing.

Also I tried, re-downloading build-tools 27.0.3 with the sdkmanager cli.

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.0.4..

Comment: 32 bit and I have 3GB ram so I cannot follow the react getting started document as I cannot install Android studio. So I am using the sdk tools CLI(they removed the UI) to install the packages. Just for information: the sdk folder is added to path in the .bashrc file also I have set the Android home variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run the tools on linux 32 bit, but it is not supported. The supported systems are Windows (both 32 and 64 bit), Mac OS 64 bit and Linux 64 bit.

Here's more info one the Android Studio's page: https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads

Comment: isnt just the android studio available for 64 bit? It also applies for the sdk tools?

Comment: Yes, it also applies to the build tools, including aapt2.

Comment: Thank you so much. You saved me a lot of time. I was going to re-install everything from the beginning.

Comment: No problem, maybe try using a different machine or VM.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using https://expo.io, especially if you're just starting out.

It would also fix your resources' problem; you don't need an emulator, as you can test on your actual phone with hot reloading and all the good stuff.

Comment: I was following codedamn(youtube channel) react-native tutorials.